# sed search for line and remove the first character of the following ten lines

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a file with links in it. the links are commented out. I would like to use sed or awk to search for a specific string and then remove the first character of the following ten lines.

As far as I know, I can search with sed in the following way

```
sed -n '/StringToSearchFor/p' file
```

With awk I would write the following

```
awk '/pattern/ {print $1}'
```

But how could I delete the first character of the following ten lines?

The manual page of sed and awk are a huge. So please do not point to them beside you have a search string for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `The manual page of sed and awk are a huge` they really aren't.

Comment: yes, just 2000+ lines, not at all huge

Comment: Sed is 177 lines without blank lines. awk is 1365. Both together are less than 10 minutes reading...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk -v s='StringToSearchFor' '$0 ~ s{n=NR} NR<=n+10{$0 = substr($0, 2)} 1' file
```

Comment: doesn't work for me. could it be related to gawk instead of awk?

Comment: No it works fine using BSD awk as well. If you include a sample input in question I can provide you a working demo on ideone.com

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 's/^.// if $l > 0 && $l--; $l = 10 if /StringToSearchFor/'
```

- `$l` keeps the number of lines to remove the first character from. It's set to 10 on each encounter of the search pattern.
- When there are still lines to remove the first character from (`$l > 0`), it's removed and the number of lines is decremented (`$l--`).
- `s/^.//` just removes the first character. It might be faster to use `substr $_, 0, 1, q()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
awk '/pattern/ { p=11 }
    p && p-- <= 10 { print substr($0, 2); next }
    1'
```

When we see the pattern, we set `p`. When `p` is set but smaller, i.e. on the ten subsequent lines, we print a substring; otherwise, the `1` is a shorthand for printing all other lines, in their entirety. The `next` causes Awk to start ov r with the next input line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a heavy `sed` version below. It prints the line matching the pattern and the following 10 lines without their first char, and quit:

```
sed -n '/StringToSearchFor/{p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p;q}' java0.log
```

`/StringToSearchFor/{ ... }`: defines a block of commands to execute when the current line is matching the regex.

`sed` commands are letters:

- `p`: print the current line (pattern space)
- `n` with `sed -n`: empty the pattern space and read in the next line
- `s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p`: print all chars except the first one.
- `q`: quit

Using 10 times `n;s/^.\(.*\)$/\1/p`: print 10 lines without their first char.

Comment: With GNU sed, you can simplify a bit, using the `+N` form of address: `/StringToSearchFor/,+10{//!s/^.//}` or the like

Answer (score 0):

another `awk`

```
awk 'p&&p--{sub(/^./,"")} /pattern/{p=10} 1' file
```

remove first chars of the 10 lines following the pattern.

Comment: You don't need the anchor, it matches left to right anyway.

Comment: Yes indeed, unneeded.